# Xamarin.UITest Android ScrollView does not expose child element

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I am Automating an android App using Xamarin UITest framework and having issues in identifying the UI Elelement within a scrollview widget. REPL command tool for some reason doesn't give me the details of the child elements within a scrollView. 
Below is my REPL tree command output 
[Repl output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlw3v.png)

[App screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idwuW.png)

The highlighted text is a scrollview and it doesnt appear in the REPL command line output.

Android API level is 16.

Any help or suggestion greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but below line of code somehow allows access to the items in the scrollview.

```
app.PressUserAction(Xamarin.UITest.Android.UserAction.Unspecified);
app.ScrollDown();
app.ScrollUp();
app.ScrollTo(<AppQuery>);
```

Just posting in case anyone stuck with this issue.